# How do I subtract time from a timer in Javascript if a certain condition is true?

Tags: javascript

I am making a riddle, where the people who try to solve it have 45 minutes to solve the riddle, and when they don't answer correctly, I want the timer to go down five minutes, to prevent them from just guessing the answers. How could I do it, I am very new to using javascript, this is the first time I'm working with it.

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
var start = Date.now(),
    diff,
    minutes,
    seconds;

var cat1 = ($("input[@name=Verdachte]:checked").val() != "2"); 
var cat2 = ($("input[@name=Moordwapen]:checked").val() != "4"); 

function timer() {
    diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);

    minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
    seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;


        if (diff <= 0) {
        start = Date.now() + 1000;
        }
    };


    timer();
    setInterval(timer, 1000);
}
window.onload = function () {
var fortyfiveMinutes = 60 * 45,
    display = document.querySelector('#time');
startTimer(fortyfiveMinutes,display);}
```

I want the timer to go down five minutes when cat1 is true, and/or when cat2 is true.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of timer, just check the input, and if it is true, disable the input and increase the time:

```
 var cat1 = $("input[@name=Verdachte]:checked");

 if(cat1.val() === "2") {
   cat1.val("you are right :)");
   cat1.attr("disabled", true);
   start -= 1000 * 60 * 5;
 }

 //...
```

... that would be even more elegant with event handlers ...

Comment: Ok, so now I only want it to happen when they click the "results" button, so I have a div:


                   <div id="results">
            Versturen
                   </div>

And the code:

  var cat1 = $("input[@name=Verdachte]:checked");
 
  $("#results").click(function(){
  if(cat1.val() === "2") {
  cat1.val("you are right :)");
  cat1.attr("disabled", true);
  start -= 1000 * 60 * 5;
  }
  }
But that doesn't work

Comment: the timer just disappears completely